# why am I getting error on compile time in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I am having this error while executing the `setup:di:compile` command

```
$ php bin/magento s:d:c
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface in vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:116
Stack trace:
#0 vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(108): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Symfony\\Compone...', Array)
#1 vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Symfony\\Compone...')
#2 vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(160): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Symfony\\Compone...')
#3 vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(246): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\F in vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 116

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface in vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:116
Stack trace:
#0 vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(108): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Symfony\\Compone...', Array)
#1 vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Symfony\\Compone...')
#2 vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(160): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Symfony\\Compone...')
#3 vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(246): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\F in vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 116
```

Answer (score 0):

i thing the issue is due any custom module di.xml file In case your interface still won't be loaded, check your di.xml and validate that a preference is available.
i hope you understand what i want to explain you
for info check below link Abstraction-implementation mappings topic
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/build/di-xml-file.html